# Webpack multi-entry point with different path/name?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following example of multiple entries in our SPA:

```
entry: {
        "main-1": ["./src/js/main-1.js"],
        "main-2": ["./src/js/main-2.js"],
        "main-3": ["./src/js/main-3.js"]
    },

 output: {
        path: DIST_FOLDER,
        filename: "js/[name]." + BUILD_VERSION + ".js",
        chunkFilename: "js/[name]." + BUILD_VERSION + ".js"
    },
```

The following generates these files:

- DIST_FOLDER/js/main-1.iq3gsj55.js
- DIST_FOLDER/js/main-2.iq3gsj55.js
- DIST_FOLDER/js/main-3.iq3gsj55.js

The problem is that I would like the following structure:

- DIST_FOLDER/js/main-1.iq3gsj55.js
- DIST_FOLDER/js/main-2.iq3gsj55.js
- **DIST_FOLDER/main-3.js**

Notice the third entry does not get BUILD_NUMBER and is outside the js folder.

Is there a way to specify a function in the output.filename where I can insert some logic generating different paths and names, or all entries must follow the same structure?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I can pass a function to entries like:

```
 entry: webpackCommon.getEntries([
        "main-1",
        "main-2",
        "main-3"
    ]),
```

and then do any logic so I can build my own entry object using a path as name of the entry and use the [name] in the output configuration.